# failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED, Freezes and IO errors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux

Here is the latest error that I got:

```
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x70000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/00:80:90:4d:10/01:00:06:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 131072 in
                                           res 40/00:84:90:4d:10/00:00:06:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:88:b8:9c:b1/00:00:07:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 in
                                           res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x5 (timeout)
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:90:c8:20:25/00:00:06:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 in
                                           res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x5 (timeout)
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5: EH complete
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x14 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/00:10:90:4d:10/01:00:06:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 131072 in
                                           res 41/40:00:90:4d:10/00:01:06:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: error: { UNC }
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 10 4d 90 00 01 00 00
Mar 31 12:16:17 hristo-ws kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 101731728
```

What could this mean? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer tries to communicate with the disk on ata5 that failed.

1. Check the SMART data from your disk to see if your disk turned bad
2. And check the connections / cables to your drive